# Mongoose Model.find() returns whole query instead of document

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to simply console.log the output of the mongoose function model.find()
I am using `node.js version 18.14.0, "express": "^4.18.2",     "mongoose": "^7.0.0",`

I have the following issues: model.find no longer accepts callbacks, so I tried to create a variable to console.log the output of model.find():

```
`const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ejs = require('ejs');


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const articleSchema = {
title: String,
content: String
};

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

app.get("/articles", function(req, res){
    let docs = Article.find()
    console.log(docs);  
    });`
```

expected output would be 3 documents with a title and content, that I manually added through 3T, if I use the db.articles.find() command within mongosh, or if I check for the articles through mongoDB Atlas, they show up normally.
I instead receive the following output:

`Query {   _mongooseOptions: {},   _transforms: [],   _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },   _executionStack: null,   mongooseCollection: Collection {     collection: null,     Promise: [Function: Promise],     modelName: 'Article',     _closed: false,     opts: {       autoIndex: true,       autoCreate: true,       schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},       capped: false,       Promise: undefined,       '$wasForceClosed': undefined     },     name: 'articles',     collectionName: 'articles',     conn: NativeConnection {       base: [Mongoose],       collections: [Object],       models: [Object],       config: {},       replica: false,       options: null,       otherDbs: [],       relatedDbs: {},       states: [Object: null prototype],       _readyState: 2,       _closeCalled: false,       _hasOpened: false,       plugins: [],       id: 0,       _queue: [Array],       _listening: false,       _connectionOptions: [Object],       _connectionString: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB',       client: [MongoClient],       '$initialConnection': [Promise]     },     queue: [],     buffer: true,     emitter: EventEmitter {       _events: [Object: null prototype] {},       _eventsCount: 0,       _maxListeners: undefined,       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false     }   },   model: Model { Article },   schema: Schema {     obj: { title: [Function: String], content: [Function: String] },     paths: {       title: [SchemaString],       content: [SchemaString],       _id: [ObjectId],       __v: [SchemaNumber]     },     aliases: {},     subpaths: {},     virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },     singleNestedPaths: {},     nested: {},     inherits: {},     callQueue: [],     _indexes: [],     methods: {},     methodOptions: {},     statics: {},     tree: {       title: [Function: String],       content: [Function: String],       _id: [Object],       __v: [Function: Number],       id: [VirtualType]     },     query: {},     childSchemas: [],     plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],     '$id': 1,     mapPaths: [],     s: { hooks: [Kareem] },     _userProvidedOptions: {},     options: {       typeKey: 'type',       id: true,       _id: true,       validateBeforeSave: true,       read: null,       shardKey: null,       discriminatorKey: '__t',       autoIndex: null,       minimize: true,       optimisticConcurrency: false,       versionKey: '__v',       capped: false,       bufferCommands: true,       strictQuery: false,       strict: true,       pluralization: true     },     '$globalPluginsApplied': true   },   op: 'find',   options: {},   _conditions: {},   _fields: undefined,   _updateDoc: undefined,   _path: undefined,   _distinctDoc: undefined,   _collection: NodeCollection {     collection: Collection {       collection: null,       Promise: [Function: Promise],       modelName: 'Article',       _closed: false,       opts: [Object],       name: 'articles',       collectionName: 'articles',       conn: [NativeConnection],       queue: [],       buffer: true,       emitter: [EventEmitter]`your text     `},     collectionName: 'articles'   },   _traceFunction: undefined,   '$useProjection': true }`

Answer (score 0):

that's happen because you were not connected to db yet

replace `mongoose.connect...` to be like below

```
const connectToDb = async () =>{
 await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});
}
connectToDb()
```

Comment: Runs into the same timeout-error: const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `articles.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the error was in the connection string.

`mongodb://localhost:27017` does not work anymore, you need to use  `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can solve it.

First change the connection from this **"mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB"** to this **"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/WikiDB"** Because when we try to connect to the mongoose the **localhost** doesn't work so instead we use the Ip address of the localhost that is **127.0.0.1**

Use the below code to check if you have successfully connected or not.

```
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/WikiDB").then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected Successfully")
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log("Connection Failed ", e)
})
```

And here is the solution for the Model.find():

```
   app.get("/articles", async (req, res) => {
    let docs = await Article.find()
    console.log(docs);  
});
```

Comment: Use the async function instead of the normal function then only the Article.find() will be able to find all the articles.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced an issue like this today I banged my head all day around and finally found a solution.

The correct answer to your question would be to use await in the model.find() method.
Please note that you've to put this in an aysnc method else this will throw an error
again.

```
app.get("/articles", async (req, res) => {
    let docs = await Article.find()
    console.log(docs);  
});
```

This part will get your job done.

Comment: Hi, the author claims that the solution was in the connection string. Are you sure this is the correct solution?