# How to fail a MongoDB script if connection to DB fails

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

If I run the following in Mongosh nothing will fail even though I do not have a DB called `not_a_db`.

```
let connect = Mongo("mongodb://localhost/");
let db = connect.getDB("not_a_db");
```

I can even get collections on the DB that doesn't exist without error and run commands. The only thing that suggests anything is wrong is no documents will be returned e.g. `mongoCollection.countDocuments();` will always be zero.

Is there a way to throw an error when a DB or Collection don't exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if mongodb database exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049722/check-if-mongodb-database-exists)

Comment: you were not connected to database yet.

Comment: please refer to this link where i just post it a few hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/75650466/9267467

Comment: @ray having to manually check each time isn't ideal. However, if there's no other option this is the answer. I'll give some time for people to suggest more elegant solutions before marking it.